I have created a field group in the ACF plugin, how do I display the field group?
I created a field group in the ACF plugin and added a field with the field group type. How do I correctly display it in the page template?

I display them like this, but the entire block with this layout simply does not appear.
<?php
    $cifr = get_field('cifr');
    if ($cifr) :
        $client = $cifr['client'];
        $workout = $cifr['workout'];
        $teams = $cifr['teams'];
        $projectworks = $cifr['projectworks'];
    ?>
    <section id="counter" class="section-padding">
      <div class="overlay dark-overlay"></div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <div class="counter-stat">
              <i class="icofont icofont-heart"></i>
              <span class="counter"><?php echo esc_html($client); ?></span>
              <h5>client</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <div class="counter-stat">
              <i class="icofont icofont-rocket"></i>
              <span class="counter"><?php echo esc_html($workout); ?></span></span>
              <h5>workout</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <div class="counter-stat">
              <i class="icofont icofont-hand-power"></i>
              <span class="counter"><?php echo esc_html($teams); ?></span></span>
              <h5>team</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <div class="counter-stat">
              <i class="icofont icofont-shield-alt"></i>
              <span class="counter"><?php echo esc_html($projectworks); ?></span></span>
              <h5>projectworks</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <?php
    endif;
    ?>


You might need CSS to fix the design changes, can you please share the website URL so I can check the issue.

at the moment it is on the local machine =(

If you remove the lines of ACF code, everything will work
